# Where can I download legend for Corine land cover 2006 classes?

Tags: data-request

I would like to have a legend for classes of Corine Land Cover 2006. I was only able to find the [legend for Corine 2000](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-100-m-version-9-2007/corine-land-cover-2000-classes-and-rgb-color-codes/clc2000legend.xls), but I was not able to find the same for CLC 2006. In XLS or CSV.

(The classsification probably hasn't changed, but I would like to officially download the 2006 version)

And preferably, both in English and Czech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found what you are looking for by googling. This PDF is labeled the CLC 2006 Legend.

http://sia.eionet.europa.eu/CLC2006/CLC_Legeng.pdf

They also have the legend as an image on this page:

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/figures/corine-land-cover-2006-by-country/legend

I also found the spreadsheet version for 1990.

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-clc1990-250-m-version-8-2005/corine-land-cover-1990-classes-and-rgb-color-codes/clc1990legend.xls

As a courtesy, I compared the 2000 XLS spreadsheet to the 2006 PDF. The data is identical.

Comment: I have found this as well. So you haven't found the XLS for 2006 either? That's a shame... it seems it actually is not accessible. Thank you anyways! (The first sentence is not true though - you haven't found what I was looking for :-))

Comment: @Thomas - The legend for 2000 and 2006 are identical. Just use the 2000 legend XLS. When you open the 2000 legend XLS, you also see the spreadsheet sheet name is 1990 legend. The legend is identica for 1990, 2000 and 2006.